# how do you change the value in the input using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an input with a value that is still dummy, when you click the pencil button the value can be changed in accordance with the input, how do I do that?
and when entered new values are automatically saved

this is my html (click pencil and input)

```
<span id="changeTitle" style="cursor:pointer;">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span>
<input type="text" name="title" value="Love at The First Sight" id="sectionTitle" class="input-title">
```

and this is my jquery

```
$('#changeTitle').on('click', function(){
   var newText = $("input[name='title']").val();
   $('#sectionTitle').text(newText);
});
```

Comment: change the event from click to change?

Comment: You are updating the value of the input with previous value only. So even if you use `val` instead of `text` , you may not notice any change

Comment: @matpol yes right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.val()` method instead of `.text()`:

```
$('#changeTitle').on('click', function(){
   var newText = $("input[name='title']").val();
   $('#sectionTitle').val(newText);
});
```

Comment: `<input type="text" name="title" id="sectionTitle"` - just saying, in OPs code they're the same input - so this does nothing - unless OP is hiding something from us...

Answer (score 2):

Here, `sectionTitle` is actually an `input` textbox and as mentioned in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/text/):

> The **`.text()`** method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of `input` or `textarea` elements, use the **`.val()`** method.

So, instead of using `$('#sectionTitle').text(newText);` you can use:

```
$('#sectionTitle').val(newText);
```